# how to set a WP Plugin's url

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, widgets

I am taking my first steps with developing on WP and so far I have been successfully able to play around with a custom widget that prints all necessary html to load a calendar with fullcalendar.js. So far so good. The next thing I would like is to have a url feeding the calendar with a set of data extracted from a specific post type set. Do I need to created a new widget for that functionality and how do I let know WP on what url to call my widget? ex. /my/custom/url/feed/json

thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure to understand. you want an URL that show datas of the events ? where event is a custom post type ?

Comment: yes exactly, I would like to have an end point that my javascript would call in order to get the data to feed the js widget.

Comment: to use that you need to [enable REST on the post type definition](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/) but if that don't output the wanted datas, you can [create a new endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [WordPress' REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

It probably makes sense, to [create a custom endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), where you can in detail define what results you need. Something along the lines of

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'kostas_calendar/v1', '/feed/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'kostas_calendar_endpoint_feed',
  ) );
} );

function kostas_calendar_endpoint_feed( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  // your code
}
```